# Retreive all child categories - sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have Categories stored in a single table.

Where there is no limit on number of childerns.

I want to fetch all the linked childern categories for the provided category id:

The reason for getting the hierarchy is that I need to update the path field for each category that is either newly created or updated. I need to maintain the path field

Table name: `categories`

```
id  parentId    name    path                         
A1   null       Cat 1   Cat 1                   
A2   A1         Cat 2   Cat 1 > Cat 2           
A3   A2         Cat 3   Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3   
A4   null       Cat A   Cat A                   
A5   A4         Cat B   Cat A > Cat B
```

Now I want to fetch hierarchy for `id: 1`

What I have tried so far is:

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parentId) AS (
    select
        id,
        name,
        parentId
    from
        categories
    where
        parentId = 'A1'
    union
    all
    select
        c.id,
        c.name,
        c.parentId
    from
        categories c
        inner join cte on c.parentId = cte.id
)
select
    *
from
    cte;
```

The above query returns:

```
[
    {
        id: A1,
        parentId: null,
        name: Cat 1,
        path: Cat 1
    },
    {
        id: A2,
        parentId: A1,
        name: Cat 2,
        path: Cat 1 > Cat 2
    }
]
```

But I want this:

```
[
    {
        id: A2,
        parentId: A1,
        name: Cat 2,
        path: Cat 1 > Cat 2
    },
    {
        id: A3,
        parentId: A2,
        name: Cat 3,
        path: Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3
    }
]
```

If I provide `id: 2`, in that case I am expecting:

```
[
    {
        id: A3,
        parentId: A2,
        name: Cat 3,
        path: Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3
    }
]
```

There is something that I am doing wrong with the query, can anyone identify?

Here is reproduced scenario: https://dbfiddle.uk/Beefs-UH

IMPORTANT NOTE:
The primary key i.e id is a unique identifier string not an integer. So the records cannot be sorted on id.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the up-hierarchy try the following:

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parentId, path, ord) as 
(
  select id, name, parentId, path, 1 as ord
  from  categories
  where id = 'A2'
  union all
  select c.id, c.name, c.parentId, c.path, t.ord+1
  from categories c join cte t
  on t.parentId = c.id 
)
select * from cte
order by ord desc;
```

Here, we order the results by the generated 'ord' value, you don't need to order by the id.

To get the down-hierarchy, use the following:

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parentId, path, ord) as 
(
  select id, name, parentId, path, 1 as ord
  from  categories
  where id = 'A2'
  union all
  select c.id, c.name, c.parentId, c.path, t.ord+1
  from categories c join cte t
  on c.parentId = t.id 
)
select * from cte
order by ord;
```

To get the full hierachy (up and down), you can union the results of the both recursive queries as the following:

```
with recursive cte(id, name, parentId, path, ord) as 
(
  select id, name, parentId, path, 1 as ord
  from  categories
  where id = 'A2'
  union all
  select c.id, c.name, c.parentId, c.path, t.ord+1
  from categories c join cte t
  on t.parentId = c.id 
),
cte2(id, name, parentId, path, ord) as 
(
  select id, name, parentId, path,0 as ord 
  from  categories
  where id = 'A2'
  union all
  select c.id, c.name, c.parentId, c.path, ord-1
  from categories c join cte2 t
  on c.parentId = t.id 
)
select id, name, parentId, path from
(
  select *  from cte
  union all
  select *  from cte2
) T
where ord <> 0 /*to avoid id = 'A2' duplication (one from cte and one from cte2)*/
order by ord desc
```

Since you are storing the full path for each id, you can try another approach using self-join as the following:

For up-hierarchy:

```
select C1.id, C1.parentId, C1.name, C1.path
from categories C1 join categories C2
on C2.path like CONCAT('%', C1.name, '%')
where C2.id='A2'
order by length(C1.path)
```

Here, we used the `length(path)` to order the results, this will guarantee that the most upper parent appears first and the lowest child appears last.

For down-hierarchy, use `on C1.path like CONCAT('%', C2.name, '%')`.

For full hierarchy, use `on C1.path like CONCAT('%', C2.name, '%') or C2.path like CONCAT('%', C1.name, '%')`.

See a [demo on MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/-zI8ojK5).

See a [demo on SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/zhOhWlPh) (with minor modifications).

Comment: I also need an exception where I want to fetch current record and all its complete nested childrens heirarchy

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the expected output for this requirement?

Comment: In the very first case I needed all the upper and lower hierarchy,

Comment: In this case, you may use `union` with the two recursive queries, and for the join query use `ON C1.path LIKE CONCAT('%', C2.name, '%') OR C2.path LIKE CONCAT('%', C1.name, '%')`. Check this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/To_dbhBo).

Comment: Would this query work for MS SQL aswell? Since I am thinking of switching to MS SQL

Comment: Yes, it will, just remove the `recursive` keyword. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WlMtzV3p)

Comment: here one thing to mention, that id is a string and we cannot apply sorting on id

Comment: When I run your query in MS SQL, it gives and error: The multi-part identifier cte.id could not be bound

Comment: Keep in mind that id is a unique identifier string uid

Comment: *id is a string and we cannot apply sorting on id*, why not? Also, [chek this](https://dbfiddle.uk/ytNkQM2D) on MS SQL with id as string.

Comment: Id is a unique identifier string like this: EDDY4UT-655HFBR-RUE78D-GDGJ34H9A

Comment: Also I would suggest you to check my updated question

Comment: I updated the answer, I hope this covers all of the issues you mentioned.

Comment: You solution fails in this senario: https://dbfiddle.uk/3AbJq7Ju

Comment: No, it doesn't fail, your are using `where id='A2'` (except the first query), A2 in this sample data has no down hierarchy and only one level up hierarchy (A1).  Check this for `id=A1` instead, https://dbfiddle.uk/eiNMe96n

Comment: So shouldnt this return all the records with parentId = 'A2'?

Comment: Yes, but there is no row where parentId = 'A2' in this sample. All the rows have parentId = 'A1', so it's one parent here which is A1 !

Comment: Could we sort these records by defining a level column?

Comment: The level is already there, the 'ord' in the recursive query is the level.

Comment: Also do you know how to transform same query in TypeOrm?

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could help you in typeorm.

Comment: How can we fetch all the upper heirarchy?

Comment: It's already included with the answer, the first query check this for A3 https://dbfiddle.uk/kp-Yi0Sw

Answer (score 1):

You left out the root node from your result set by applying a filter on the "parentId" column. (Your root has no parent.)

Here's an aproach that works:

1. Use your desired id for filtering your initial step. (I used your first example, id = 3)
2. Follow the "parent-chain" until root is reached.
   (Cat 3's parent is Cat 2, Cat 2's parent is Cat 1, and Cat 1 has no parent: root is reached.)
3. Run a simple select.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, name, parentId, path, lvl) AS (
  -- Initial step
  SELECT
     id,
     name,
     parentId,
     path,
     1
  FROM categories
  WHERE id = 3

  UNION ALL

  -- Follow the "parent-chain"
  SELECT
     cat.id,
     cat.name,
     cat.parentId,
     cat.path,
     cte.lvl + 1
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN categories cat
    ON cte.parentId = cat.id
)

SELECT id, name, parentId, path
FROM cte
ORDER BY lvl DESC
;
```

But since you want to maintain the "path" field, it might be easier to calculate all paths by using a recursive CTE and then check for mismatch:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (root, id, name, parentId, old_path, new_path, lvl) AS (
  SELECT
      id,
      id,
      name,
      parentId,
      path,
      name,
      1
  FROM categories
  WHERE parentId = 0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
      cte.root,
      cat.id,
      cat.name,
      cat.parentId,
      cat.path,
      CONCAT(cte.name, ' > ', cat.name),
      cte.lvl + 1
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN categories cat
    ON cte.id = cat.parentId
)
  
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE old_path != new_path
ORDER BY root, lvl
;
```

Solution for your after-edit problem:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, name, parentId, path, lvl) AS (
  SELECT
     id,
     name,
     parentId,
     path,
     1
  FROM categories
  WHERE id = 2

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
     cat.id,
     cat.name,
     cat.parentId,
     cat.path,
     cte.lvl + 1
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN categories cat
    ON cte.id = cat.parentId
)

SELECT id, name, parentId, path
FROM cte
ORDER BY lvl ASC
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/agO_kNXf

Comment: Can you check my updated question. Also would this query works fine for MS SQL aswell?

Comment: Edited my response. Also, here's a dbfiddle link for the mssql version: https://dbfiddle.uk/spE1QUBe

Comment: Any idea how can we fetch the upper heirarchy?

Answer (score 0):

The data in `categories` table represents a tree structure connected by nodes (category):

1. a node could have zero or more child nodes; and
2. a node could have zero or one parent node.

Step 1. Create the table schema (with slight modification)

```
-- create table
create table tree (
    id          int,
    parent_id   int,
    name        varchar(100),
    path        varchar(200)
);
```

Step 2. Generate test data and each node could have zero to three children nodes (Please feel free to modify CTE to include more `union all`s.

```
insert into tree
with recursive cte (parent_id, id, name, path) as (
    select 0                      as parent_id, 
           1                      as id,
           convert(1, char(100))  as name,
           convert(1, char(100))  as path
    union all
    select id                     as parent_id,
           id*10 + 1              as id,
           convert(id*10+1, char) as name,
           concat(path,'>',convert(id*10+1, char)) as path
      from cte
     where id < 1000
       and floor(rand()*2) = 1
    union all
    select id                     as parent_id,
           id*10 + 2              as id,
           convert(id*10+2, char) as name,
           concat(path,'>',convert(id*10+2, char)) as path
      from cte
     where id < 1000
       and floor(rand()*2) = 1
    union all
    select id                     as parent_id,
           id*10 + 3              as id,
           convert(id*10+3, char) as name,
           concat(path,'>',convert(id*10+3, char)) as path
      from cte
     where id < 1000
       and floor(rand()*2) = 1
)
select id, parent_id, name, path
  from cte
 order by 1,2;
```

My test data looks like this (YMMV because of RAND() function):

```
id  |parent_id|name|path         |
----+---------+----+-------------+
   1|        0|1   |1            |
  11|        1|11  |1>11         |
  12|        1|12  |1>12         |
  13|        1|13  |1>13         |
 112|       11|112 |1>11>112     |
 121|       12|121 |1>12>121     |
 122|       12|122 |1>12>122     |
 123|       12|123 |1>12>123     |
 132|       13|132 |1>13>132     |
 133|       13|133 |1>13>133     |
1121|      112|1121|1>11>112>1121|
1211|      121|1211|1>12>121>1211|
1221|      122|1221|1>12>122>1221|
1222|      122|1222|1>12>122>1222|
1233|      123|1233|1>12>123>1233|
1321|      132|1321|1>13>132>1321|
1332|      133|1332|1>13>133>1332|
1333|      133|1333|1>13>133>1333|
```

The tree can be visualized as below:
[image]

Step 3. Retrieve all linked parent nodes and children nodes (ie. ID=12)

```
-- get all linked parent & child nodes
with recursive cte_tree_parent (id, parent_id, name, path) as (
    select id, 
           parent_id,
           name,
           path
      from tree
     where id = 12
     union all
    select p.id,
           p.parent_id,
           p.name,
           p.path
      from cte_tree_parent c  
      join tree p      
        on c.parent_id = p.id),
cte_tree_child (id, parent_id, name, path) as (
    select id, 
           parent_id,
           name,
           path
      from tree
     where id = 12
     union all
    select c.id,
           c.parent_id,
           c.name,
           c.path
      from cte_tree_child p  
      join tree c      
        on p.id = c.parent_id)
select id, parent_id, name, path
  from cte_tree_parent
 union
select id, parent_id, name, path
  from cte_tree_child
 order by path;
```

Result:

```
id  |parent_id|name|path         |
----+---------+----+-------------+
   1|        0|1   |1            |
  12|        1|12  |1>12         |
 121|       12|121 |1>12>121     |
1211|      121|1211|1>12>121>1211|
 122|       12|122 |1>12>122     |
1221|      122|1221|1>12>122>1221|
1222|      122|1222|1>12>122>1222|
 123|       12|123 |1>12>123     |
1233|      123|1233|1>12>123>1233|
```